# Chrome extension that splits current tab into its own window, and resizes the two windows equally

Tags: chrome

When I present a document during a Google Meet or Zoom meeting, I want to see both:

- the meeting window (to see everyone's faces and comments),
- and the presented document (a browser tab showing Google Documents, a wiki, or anything else).

I only have a single monitor, I always have hundreds of tabs open, many pinned and many grouped. Manually splitting and resizing windows in too much of a pain and too error-prone (with that many tabs split screen means that most tabs are too small to identify, or end up in the overflow menu where they are impossible to find quickly).

I am looking for a Chrome browser extension that does the following with 1 click (or 1 shortcut, or ideally automatically whenever I start presenting a document in Google Meet):

- Reduce the width of the current window by half
- Open a new window of the same size
- Move these windows so that they are both visible
- Transfer the current tab (ideally the presented tab) to the new window

Requirements:

- Free
- Ideally open source
- Does not mess with with pinned tabs and grouped tabs (so not Dualless)

Answer (score 0):

[Tab to Window](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-to-windowpopup-keyboa/adbkphmimfcaeonicpmamfddbbnphikh) does this, simply by pressing alt-x (command-x on Mac).

Unfortunately it seems that it can't do it automatically whenever I start presenting a document in Google Meet.

Guide: https://acarabott.github.io/tabToWindow
License: Free and open source, MIT.
Source code: https://github.com/acarabott/tabToWindow